# Java version indicates SE 6, Java Control Panel SE 8

Tags: mac, java

I'm trying to get the Java 7 as the default version on my machine, running Mac OS X 10.9.3. When I run:

```
java -version
```

I get:

```
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)
```

When I run:

```
javac -version
```

I get:

```
javac 1.6.0_65
```

When I go into System Preferences --> Java --> Update, I see:

```
Your system has the recommended vesion of Java.

Java 8 Update 05.
```

I have a few questions:

1. Why does my Java Control Panel claim I have Java 8, but my work in the terminal (when checking my Java version) says otherwise?
2. I just downloaded the .dmg file for Java SE 7 from Oracle's site and installed, though it's nowhere to be seen. Where could this be found on my machine?

Answer (score 0):

The JVM in your path setting:

`(Windows 10) WindowsExplorer --> ThisPC --> (right-click) Properties --> AdvancedSystemSettings --> EnvironmentVariables --> Path`

is different from the JVM you installed last.

In the above you probably installed JVM-8 last, but your JVM-6 is right at the front of the PATH variable list.

The PATH variable is the list of places to search for executables when invoked at the command line.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the discrepancy in your case is because you're looking at the JRE and JDK and trying to compare the two. The current JDK that you have is Java 8 , whereas the current JRE that you have is 1.6. 0_65